# How to refactor rename just like in Android Studio?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm finding it difficult just to do a simple function like right clicking and Refactoring in Android Studio to change a variable name everywhere, but on VS Code it gives some other options that are even greyed out.

Without going into too much, how do I just rename a variable everywhere in my code just like in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the cursor within the variable and hit F2 (Windows) or fn-F2 (Mac).  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol